# Restrict Access To Certain File From Other Programs And Users While Running

Tags: c#, filestream, file-access

I am in process of building an app which writes data continuously to a file. When I start the program the file is created and starts being written to. 
However I noticed that **sometimes** if I have Windows Explorer open, access to the file is denied to my app, and an error is thrown.

```
fs = new System.IO.FileStream(location, 
                              System.IO.FileMode.Open, 
                              System.IO.FileAccess.Write, 
                              System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

So how do I restrict access to this file so only my app can access it, not any other programs?

Comment: _"and an error is thrown"_ - what error?

Comment: Can't remember the exact error but its close to "Access to the file is denied".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the last parameter from `System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite` to `System.IO.FileShare.None`.

That locks the file in `location` exclusively as long as this stream is open and no other app can read, modify or delete that file except your own `FileStream`.

In fact this isn't only true for other apps - even your own app can't open another `FileStream` of that file. So keep it open as long as you need but don't forget to correctly dispose the `FileStream` after use.